# Is there a free hosting site for electrical engineering projects?

Tags: simulation, cpu, website, open-hardware

I've recently completed a functional CPU and instruction set simulated in Logisim and an example program for it. I'm now just wrapping up all the documentation for the whole design and would like to post it up so people can get to it as an educational resource. However, I'm not interested in paying to host it since I just spent a few months designing it. Is there some place that hosts projects like this in the way that Sourceforge hosts software projects and Opencores hosts soft processors? Thanks in advance for any direction you can give me.

Comment: It sounds like you have text-based data, which would work fine on Sourceforge, Github, or a software hosting site.  Are there large binaries that need to be included in your VCS?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's still young but seems what http://upverter.com/ was created for. Of course you could also just put the whole thing on Github as well.

Comment: Upverter looks much better than "treat it like source code and put it on github".  It has a very similar layout, too, no?

Answer (score 0):

The [Open Circuits wiki](http://opencircuits.com/Main_Page) has free hosting for electrical engineering projects, such as the [Minimig](http://opencircuits.com/Minimig).

[Wikibooks: Microprocessor Design](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Microprocessor_Design) is a good place to collect tips for CPU design, and documents about CPU design in general -- such as a comparison of several different approaches to sequencing, rather than focusing on the one particular technique used in one particular processor.

For educational resources about one CPU design in particular, it may be more appropriate to post your design on a sub page of the [Wikiversity: Computer Architecture Lab](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Computer_Architecture_Lab) next to many other CPU designs.

If you have gerber files, consider posting them at the [Open Source Hardware Reserve Bank](http://www.oshwbank.org/) or the [Batch PCB marketplace](http://batchpcb.com/index.php/Products) to make it easier for people to get their hands on a physical circuit board.

http://upverter.com/ looks very cool -- thank you for telling me about it, nemik.